# Django queries - id vs pk

Tags: django, orm, primary-key

When writing django queries one can use both id/pk as query parameters.

```
Object.objects.get(id=1)
Object.objects.get(pk=1)
```

I know that pk stands for Primary Key and is just a shortcut, according to django's documentation. However it is not clear when one should be using id or pk.

Comment: Here is that respective docmentation: [for ``id``](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) and [for ``pk``](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Model.id and Model.pk in django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345711/whats-the-difference-between-model-id-and-model-pk-in-django)

Comment: Want to know if something is more to it https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances

Comment: Check Updated version here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Answer (score 285, accepted):

It doesn't matter. `pk` is more independent from the actual primary key field i.e. you don't need to care whether the primary key field is called `id` or `object_id` or whatever.

It also provides more consistency if you have models with different primary key fields.

Comment: `id` is also a built-in function in Python, I prefer to use pk because of that.

Comment: Yes, ``pk`` is preferable. See the [documentation of built-in function``id``](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#id) in the Python standard library. (It is the [same in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#id).)

Comment: i guess they are talking more about ORM `id` not talking about the python `id` function.

Comment: Use pk, since after a while You'll have projects with custom primary keys that aren't named ID, so it can create problems, get used to pk since it always refer to the Primary key field no matter what is the name

Answer (score 69):

In Django projects where I know that `pk` always returns `id` I prefer using `id` when it does not clash with the `id()` function (everywhere except variable names). The reason for this is that `pk` is a property which is 7 times slower than `id` since it takes time looking up `pk` attribute name in `meta`.

```
%timeit obj.id
46 ns ± 0.187 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
%timeit obj.pk
347 ns ± 11.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Here is the relevant Django code:

```
def _get_pk_val(self, meta=None):
    meta = meta or self._meta
    return getattr(self, meta.pk.attname)

def _set_pk_val(self, value):
    return setattr(self, self._meta.pk.attname, value)

pk = property(_get_pk_val, _set_pk_val)
```

It is really a rare case when I need to use a variable named `pk`. I prefer using something more verbose, like `user_id` instead of `pk`.

Following the same convention is preferable across the whole project. In your case `id` is a parameter name, not a property, so there is almost no difference in timings. Parameter names do not clash with the name of built-in `id()` function, so it is safe to use `id` here.

To sum up, it is up to you to choose whether to use field name `id` or the `pk` shortcut. If you are not developing a library for Django and use [automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields) for all models, it is safe to use `id` everywhere, which is sometimes faster. From the other hand, if you want universal access to (probably custom) primary key fields, then use `pk` everywhere. A third of a microsecond is nothing for web.