# Django model form and objects database id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a complex django object, which has properties of other class types. This gets like this:

```
class Order:
   contractor - type Person
   some other fields....
```

In my form I'd like to be able to either choose existing Person object from the dropdown or add a new one with a form. I've managed to create forms and appropriate workflow, but the problem is with saving the Order itself, I simply can't get the id of a saved Person instance. I'm doing sth like this:

```
def make_order(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    parameters = copy.copy(request.POST)
    contractor_form = ContractorForm(parameters)
    if contractor_form.is_valid():
      contractor_form.save()
      parameters['contractor'] = ???
    form = OrderForm(parameters)
    if form.is_valid():
      form.save() 
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/orders/')
  else:
    form = OrderForm()
    contractor_form = ContractorForm()

  return render_to_response('orders/make_order.html', {'order_form' : form, 'contractor_form' : contractor_form})
```

So, if POST request reaches this method I first check if ContractorForm have been filled - I assume that if the form is valid, it is meant to be used. If yes, than I save it and would like to assign the saved object's database id to appropriate field for OrderForm to find it.

All my forms are ModelForms.

The questions are:

1. Are there better ways to do this? (choose from dropdown or add in place) - better or more pythonic ;-)
2. How can I get saved objects id when using ModelForms?

**Edited**

My ContractorForm is:

```
class ContractorForm(ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Contractor
```

Nothing fancy.

Comment: On a side note, use reverse (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) instead of referencing the '/orders/' url directly in your `HttpResponseRedirect`... it'll save you tons of headaches in the future, trust me :)

Comment: Ha! You're right, I should've done that earlier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[save()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) should return the newly created instance.

```
if contractor_form.is_valid():
  instance = contractor_form.save()
  parameters['contractor'] = instance
```

where id would be `instance.id`, or even better [`instance.pk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#the-pk-property).

[`pk` vs. `id`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165865/django-queries-id-vs-pk):

> Regardless of whether you define a
>   primary key field yourself, or let
>   Django supply one for you, each model
>   will have a property called pk. It
>   behaves like a normal attribute on the
>   model, but is actually an alias for
>   whichever attribute is the primary key
>   field for the model. You can read and
>   set this value, just as you would for
>   any other attribute, and it will
>   update the correct field in the model.

***Follow-up on comment:***

Well it does work by default, so there must be something else wrong.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from models import Category

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
```

**Test in shell:**

```
In [3]: from katalog.forms import MyModelForm
In [4]: data = {'name':'Test', 'slug':'test'}
In [5]: form = MyModelForm(data)
In [6]: instance = form.save()
In [7]: instance
Out[7]: <Category: Test>
In [8]: instance.id
Out[8]: 5L
```

Comment: This was my first guess, but unfortunately it doesn't work like this. ModelForm.save() returns None. There should be a way of doing this with overloaded save() method, but this seems overcomplicated and messy.

Comment: Well, I've tested this again, and your solution works. I'll however test it more thoroughly with my specific case.