# Conditional operator giving matching query does not exist exception

Tags: python, django, django-celery

I am using a conditional statement like this in my code:

```
if not profile.client.user.id == 3:
```

Somehow that gives me `Exception: Client matching query does not exist.` exception. This is just a conditional operator, so I am not sure why am I getting this exception. Does anyone have any clue what could be going wrong?

## UserProfile Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client,null=True)
```

## Client Model

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='oauth2_client',
        blank=True, null=True)
```

## User Model

This is a standard [django user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

Comment: What's the code for `profile.client.user.id`? Is that a data descriptor?

Comment: @Eithos profile is a userprofile model and client is a foreign key, client has user as foreign key and user has id

Comment: I just don't see how we can help you with the little bit of code you've given us. There is nothing mysterious about the way the conditional operator works; it's just not what's causing your error. The error is somewhere in the code of `profile.client.user.id`. We don't even know what kind of object it is, if the `id` attribute is a descriptor (so the error could be coming from the `__get__` if that's what it is) or from `__eq__`, if it's been defined. We just have no way to figure this out without having access to that information.

Comment: Just to add to that quickly, I hadn't noticed the _django_ tag until now. If this `profile.client.user.id` is somehow familiar to people who've used it, by all means ignore what I've said if it doesn't apply. I still have trouble seeing how you'll get help without more information, though.

Comment: @Eithos Please check the edits

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pk instead of id

```
if not profile.client.user.pk == 3:
```

More their: [What's the difference between Model.id and Model.pk in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345711/whats-the-difference-between-model-id-and-model-pk-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

This means that you database is broken - `profile.client` field points to the `Client` that does not exist.  You can check it with the following query:

```
client = Client.objects.get(pk=profile.client_id)
```

If such client exists then this query will be executed normally. If client does not exist then the exception will be raised.