# django object havn't pk but have id

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have problem with objects in Django. 
My project using multiply databases. When I create object using

```
obj, _created = self.model.objects.using('default').get_or_create(pk=1)
```

obj don't have pk but have id

`ipdb> obj.pk 
ipdb> obj.id
 1`

Why this happened?

Comment: Take a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345711/whats-the-difference-between-model-id-and-model-pk-in-django and the links there

Answer (score 0):

First look this answers:
[What's the difference between Model.id and Model.pk in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345711/whats-the-difference-between-model-id-and-model-pk-in-django)
[Django queries - id vs pk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165865/django-queries-id-vs-pk)

And the doc of 'get_or_create':
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

The object has 'pk' when he was recovered from 'bd'.
Probably the object was created, check the variable '_created', it specifies whether a new object was created or was recovered from 'bd'.

Comment: Sorry i don't write that i try update this object. He exist in db, so _cretated return False