# Is there somewhere different between `pk` and `id`?

Tags: python, django

When I read the source code, I find the function use `pk` to as keyword to select data:

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    try:
        album = Album.objects.filter(pk=album_id)
    except Album.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("Album does not exist")

    context = {
        "album":album,
    }

    return render(request, "music/detail.html", context)
```

I am used to use `id`:

```
album = Album.objects.filter(id=album_id)
```

So, is there somewhere different between them?

Comment: Have you tried checking in the docs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22345711/whats-the-difference-between-model-id-and-model-pk-in-django

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django `id` field is by default the `pk` hence you can use both.

**Difference:**

But you can manually set `pk` and then it may not be `id` field