# Django Retrieving data as 5 members groups

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

when retrieving objects in Django I want it to be divided into a group like for example get all products and the result should be 4 groups each group have 5 objects I don't mean to group by property just random groups each group have five members for example when retrieving products = Product.objects.all() i want the result to be product = [ [ {id:1, price:3}, {id:2, price:3}, {id:5, price:3}], {id:6, price:3}, {id:10, price:3}, {id:1, price:3}], {id:19, price:3}, {id:1, price:3}, {id:1, price:3}] ], so i want to like to get the query a number for example 3 so that it gives me group with 3 members in each

Comment: Hopefully this isn't a product recommendation algorithm :) Because it would be a pretty bad one. Does this look like a good solution? [Django: get random object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755881/1577947)

Comment: :) no it's just ordinary groups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in method in the ORM that does this functionality so that's how I did it

`products =  [products[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(products), 3)]`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want but take a look at it. Maybe it will help.

```
products = Product.objects.all()
output = []
product_list = []
i = 1
for product in products:
    product_list.append(product)
    
    if i % 3 == 0:
        output.append(product_list)
        product_list = []

    i += 1

if product_list.length != 0:
   output.append(product_list)
```

output:

```
[ 
   [{id:1, price:3}, {id:2, price:3}, {id:5, price:3}], 
   [{id:6, price:3}, {id:10, price:3}, {id:1, price:3}], 
   [{id:19, price:3}, {id:1, price:3}, {id:1, price:3}] 
]
```

keep in mind, that with this method you will get lists with item objects not dictionaries {id:1, price:3}

Comment: Thank you fr your response but is there any built method in the orm that do that while getting the data?