# How to pull random images from database(admin) in Django?

Tags: python, django

I want to pull random images from database with there id number
This is my **models.py** code and Here i am making id field , name and image field

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from os import listdir
import os.path
from django.conf import settings
from os.path import isfile
from os.path import join as path_join
from random import choice

import internship.settings


def random_img():
    dir_path = os.path.join(internship.settings.BASE_DIR, 'media')
    files = [
        content for content in listdir(dir_path)
        if isfile(path_join(dir_path, content))
    ]
    return choice(files)


# Create your models here.
class images(models.Model):
    id_no = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')
```

so i want to pull out and show it in a template but everytime i reload the page i need to show a new images .. So
**How can i do that?** i cant able to get the logic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django get a random object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816704/django-get-a-random-object)

Comment: how to do it i need some steps to fulfil the task