# Django: get random object from database by id, but if id doesn't exist try again

Tags: django

Trying to get a random object from the database with an id.
Some ids in the database table are missing, for example, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 19, 20... so I need to make sure I don't get an error when I try to get an object.

This seems to be working.  Is there a better way.

```
def get_random_title():
  title_count = OriginalTitle.objects.count()
  random_id = random.randrange(1, title_count)
  random_title_obj = None

  while random_title_obj is None:
    try:
      random_title_obj = OriginalTitle.objects.get(id=random_id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
      continue
  return random_title_obj.title

def play(request):
  random_title = get_random_title()
  context = {
    'original_title': random_title
  }
  return render(request, 'game/game.html', context)
```

Comment: 1 and count of object is not the range of ids, you should use min and max of id.

Comment: @nft Just a comment, If you have 4 instances with ids: 1, 4, 6, 9, your `random.randrange(1, title_count)` just returns values in range: `1, 2, 3`, So, you will never get instances with IDs 4, 6, 9.

Comment: Here is the solution for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816704/django-get-a-random-object

Answer (score 2):

You can use random.sample() on a QuerySet object. or change the ordering of rows.

OriginalTitle.objects.order_by('?')[:1]

Comment: Thank you.  Would you mind showing me how to put that in my get_random_title() function by writing out the whole function.  For example, do I still need the while loop and try/except if I use that line?

Comment: def get_random_title(): return OriginalTitle.objects.order_by("?").first().title

Answer (score 2):

Using `.order_by('?')` is *expensive*. Indeed, as the [documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by):

> Note: `order_by('?')` queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using.

For most databases, it will annotate a random number to each record and then order by that number, making it linear in the size of the table.

You can return a sample of the database with:

```
def get_random_title():
  title_count = OriginalTitle.objects.count()
  idx = random.randrange(0, title_count)
  random_title_obj = OriginalTitle.objects.all()[idx].title
```

This will make two queries, but for large tables can outperform an `.order_by('?')`.

Answer (score 0):

---

```
# edit your get_random_title
def get_random_title():
  random_title_obj = OriginalTitle.objects.order_by('?')[0]
  return random_title_obj.title
```

please read more details in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23755881/18129097)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Thank you for the responses. I got rid of the get_random_title() function and just put the one line in the play() view

```
def play(request):
  random_title = OriginalTitle.objects.order_by("?").first().title
  context = {
    'original_title': random_title
  }
  return render(request, 'game/game.html', context)
```

One note to anyone who uses this answer:
I see now in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by)
that it says, "Note: order_by('?') queries may be expensive and slow, depending on the database backend you’re using."