# Django 1.8 using multiple DetailView

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to use multiple `DetailView`'s in my `views.py` but due to some reason I'm getting this error during template rendering. http://prntscr.com/7f8vql
   http://prntscr.com/7f8vlv .

My `views.py`

```
def rock_and_feat(request):
    feats = Feat.objects.order_by('-created')[:3]
    rocks = Rockinfo.objects.order_by('-rank')[:50]
    context = RequestContext(request, {
    'feats': feats, 'rocks': rocks
    })
    return render_to_response('template.html', context)


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Feat
    template_name = 'feature/detail.html' 
    context_object_name = 'feat'

class RockDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Rockinfo
    template_name = 'feature/detailrock.html' 
    context_object_name = 'rockinfo'
```

My apps `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [

url(r'^$', views.rock_and_feat, name='rock_and_feat'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.RockDetailView.as_view(),  name='detailrock'),
]
```

My project's `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', include('feature.urls', namespace="feature")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`template.html`

```
   {% block rocker %}
      {% if rocks %}
          {% for item in rocks %}

              <div class="artist-container">
              <a href="{% url 'feature:detailrock' rockinfo.id %}"><img src="{{ item.rock_img.url }}" class="artist-img" alt="Dimitri Vegas &amp; Like Mike">
               <div class="artist-info">{{ item.rock_name }}</div></a></div>
           {% endfor %}
       {% else %}
               <p>No rockers are available.</p>
       {% endif %}
              </div></div>
   {% endblock %}
```

I can't figure out what the error is about.Thanks

Comment: your detail and detailrock have the same pattern in your urls.py, perhaps it has something to do with this.

Comment: @vmonteco I tried changing the pattern but the same error came up.

Comment: check rockinfo|pprint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rememeber your question about `rock_and_feat`.

There are several things I want to mention:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.rock_and_feat, name='rock_and_feat'),
  url(r'^detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
  url(r'^rock_detail/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.RockDetailView.as_view(), name='detailrock'),
]
```

You don't have `rockinfo`. It is `item`. In this line:

```
{% url 'feature:detailrock' item.id %}
```

One more thing. Note, that `id` [is not the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165865/django-queries-id-vs-pk) as `pk`.

```
{% url 'feature:detailrock' item.pk %}
```

One last thing. This can be replaced:

```
   {% if rocks %}
      {% for item in rocks %}
          ....
      {% endfor %}
   {% else %}
       <p>No rockers are available.</p>
   {% endif %}
```

With this ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for-empty)):

```
   {% for item in rocks %}
       ...
   {% empty %}
       <p>No rockers are available.</p>
   {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

(wild guess here) Reading the error, it seems to me that `rockinfo.id` is empty or it doesn't exists (or not passed to the template), have you checked that?

Besides that, you should have two different patterns for the views

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> 1.Please check template for getting rockinfo.id and check.

`<a href="{% url 'feature:detailrock' rockinfo.id %}">`

> 2.Remove namespace from urlconf and just use `<a href="{% url 'detailrock' rockinfo.id %}">` in template.
>
> I think either 1 or 2 will work.