# Django- TypeError... post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am still pretty new to Python and Django stackoverflow has really being my strength during this journey. I am working on a Django app where car owner will list their fleet of cars and drivers interested in renting them for Taxi or Uber will make a request to rent the cars…
i basically have three models at this point the users(car owners and drivers) car listed by owners(models.Listing), and model.Rent (request being made by drivers to rent a car), i have a listView to list all the car available and a detailView for showing details of each car, i have a button on the detailed view, when clicked by a Driver i want it to take the logged in driver `request.user` instance and the primary key from the car Listing model on the detailed view and save it in the rent model… But i am getting a “TypeError at /listing/1/ (post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id’)” Below are my view.py, models.py and error messages: I have read through various similar questions here, some suggested using Listing.id instead of Listing.pk… that resulted into a ValueError. With regards to stackoverflow’s rule, i’ve spent about a week trying out suggestions from similar questions and researching elsewhere also, but none of them seem to share a close detail to what i am trying to do, from reading here and there i found out that i have to use `get_object_or_404` considering the view i’m trying to work with, but maybe i’m not using it correctly. I have to seek help here as a last resort. I really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thank you in advance.

**view.py**

```
class ListingDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Listing

    def post(self, request, pk, listing_id,  *args, **kwargs):
        car = Listing.objects.get(pk=listing_id)
        listing = get_object_or_404(Listing.pk, pk=pk)
        rent, created = Rent.objects.get_or_create(
            car_id=car,
            driver=request.user,
            )

        rent.save(request.POST, listing, rent)
        messages.info(request, "Rent request has been made succesfully.")
        return redirect('/')
```

**url.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

path('listing/<int:pk>/', ListingDetailView.as_view(), name='listing-detail'),

]
```

**models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):

    car_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    car_model = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.car_year}  {self.car_make}  {self.car_model}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('listing-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class Rent(models.Model):
    car_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    driver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**listing_detail.html**

```
<form method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="hire-car" class="btn btn-primary">Rent Car</button>
    </form>
```

**ERROR**

```
TypeError at /listing/1/

post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'

Request Method: POST

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing/1/

Django Version: 3.1

Exception Type: TypeError

Exception Value:    post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'

Exception Location: /Users/ChuzzyOfficial/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/instarydes/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py, line 101, in dispatch
Python Executable:  /Users/ChuzzyOfficial/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/instarydes/.venv/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.8.5
```

**MORE ERROR**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/listing/1/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'app.apps.AppConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ChuzzyOfficial/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/instarydes/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/ChuzzyOfficial/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/instarydes/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ChuzzyOfficial/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/instarydes/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ChuzzyOfficial/PycharmProjects/djangoProject/instarydes/.venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /listing/1/
Exception Value: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'
```

Comment: Try changing the method to `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):` then check `*args` to see what parameters you are receiving.

Comment: This question has quite a lot of long code for potential answerers to read...try scaling it down a little by using a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will make your question more readable and help others test solutions to your question without too much code.

Comment: @Mike67 args is empty and doesn't pass anything, however kwargs contains only pk

Comment: i have reduce my code to the necessary bits as advised by @monsieuralfonse64

Comment: It seems like the HTML page is not sending the listing_id.In the page, add a listing_id form element and check if the value is passed to the method.

Comment: ok i will try that, btw is it possible to just use pk instead or listing_id?

Comment: @Mike67 could you please guide me on how to do that, i'm not sure how to create a form element for listing_id because it isn't a field in my model.

Comment: Within the form (above the button), add a hidden field: `<input type="hidden" id="listing_id" name="listing_id" value="123">`. Check if that value gets passed to the function.

Comment: Okay, thank you...
When i initialize it with `listing_id=None` i got a ValueError

`raise ValueError(
ValueError: The view app.views.ListingDetailView didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
[06/Sep/2020 16:01:13] "POST /listing/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 60559`

But when i remove None i got:

`TypeError: post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'
[06/Sep/2020 16:03:35] "POST /listing/1/ HTTP/1.1" 500 65447`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had a chance to test anything out yet, but just from reading the error, here's my best guess.

The error: `post() missing 1 required positional argument: 'listing_id'`

I would interpret this as being that your post request is actually not receiving `listing_id` directly. This leads me to want to know how your URL paths are set up. If you are just using `return reverse('listing-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})`, then I am assuming `'pk'` would be the positional argument passed through, and not `'listing_id'`.

So, my plan of attack would be to understand what is actually being sent through the post request. As @Mike67 suggested, I would check out what is coming through your *args and **kwargs. Alternatively, you can have defaults for your arguments: `listing_id=None`, and then check:

`if listing_id: #you know listing_id was passed through`

However, I'd keep this more for debugging.

I'd recommend checking this article out:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views

**edit**

Upon seeing the url parameters, it kinda makes sense. You are only receiving the pk value.

However! Why not use the pk value instead of the id?

`object = ObjectClass.objects.get(pk=pk)`

You can read up on the difference here: (for most cases they will be the same)
[Django queries - id vs pk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165865/django-queries-id-vs-pk)

Alternatively, I have no idea if this will work, but I’d be interested to know what would happen if you tried: `self.get_object()`?

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have included my URL Pattern in the post, PK is surely being passed through, but i read here [link] (https://thebuild.com/blog/2010/12/22/getting-the-id-of-related-objects-in-django/) that id is always available to be used, that's why i chose to use it instead.